# Passing an array of structs to a pthread_create

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, pthreads

So I have a struct as follows:

```
struct threadData{
    string filename
    int one;
    int two;
};
```

and I created an array of these structs like this:

```
pthread_t threadID[5];
struct threadData *threadP;
threadP = new struct threadData[5];
```

then I'm passing this array of structs to a thread function as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    pthread_create(&threadID[i], NULL, threadFunction, (void * ) threadP[i]);
}
```

and this is how my threadFunction is written:

```
void *threadFunction(void * threadP[]){

}
```

I've tried various things, but I always get the error that what I pass in is not correct, how do I do this properly so that I can access and process the variables in each struct object I pass in? I have a feeling that my syntax somewhere is wrong due to me using an array of structs...I just don't know where or what exactly is wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It should be `&threadP[i]`. That's all.

Comment: why not use std::thread?

Comment: It looks like your function should be declared as `void *threadFunction(void * threadP)` and the call should be `pthread_create(&threadID[i], NULL, threadFunction, (void * ) &threadP[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

```
void *threadFunction(void * threadP[]){
```

Functions cannot have parameters of array types in C++, instead the parameter has to be a pointer, and an array used as a function argument decays to a pointer to the first element, so that declaration is equivalent to:

```
void *threadFunction(void ** threadP){
```

Which clearly isn't the right type to pass to `pthread_create`

You need to pass a function with this signature:

```
void *threadFunction(void * threadP)
```

Comment: It looks like most of your gripes here are stylistic. You hint towards the real problem, but don't explain it much. It's also a little misleading to say that you can't pass arrays to functions in C++. You can, but they "decay" to a pointer, as you point out. However, there are cases where the array syntax is actually required--such as when passing multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: e.g.: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9a.html ... Anyway, multi-dimensional arrays are irrelevant to this situation. However, I just wanted to point out that your statement is a little misleading.

Comment: Does it need explaining much? The function is the wrong type, that's why it doesn't compile. And when you have a multidimensional array you still don't have a parameter of array type, you have a _pointer to an array_. I've removed the stylistic comments and rephrased the answer anyway